# How to install all roles without skipping any using ansible-galaxy?

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-galaxy

We are trying to install roles from git using ansible-galaxy requirements.yml, But 2 roles are getting skipped while cloning.

```
command: ansible-galaxy install ssh://git@emea-aws-gitlab.sanofi.com:2222/idop-automation-team/ansible/common-utilities.git
```

roles:
AD_join
AD_join1
configure_backup/
configure_monitoring/
email_notification/
enable_controlm/
host_reachability/

AD_join and AD_join1 are the roles which is missed

````
output of ansible-galaxy install ssh://git@emea-aws-gitlab.sanofi.com:2222/idop-automation-team/ansible/common-utilities.git -vvvv 
ansible-galaxy 2.9.4
20   config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
21   configured module search path = [u'/home/gitlab-runner/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
22   ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
23   executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy
24   python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
25 Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
26 Reading requirement file at 'playbooks/requirements.yml'
27 found role {'scm': 'git', 'src': 'ssh://git@emea-aws-gitlab.sanofi.com:2222/idop-automation-team/ansible/common-utilities.git', 'version': '', 'name': 'common-utilities'} in yaml file
28 Processing role common-utilities
29 archiving ['/usr/bin/git', 'archive', '--prefix=common-utilities/', u'--output=/home/gitlab-runner/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-518eOXk8v/tmpKTPqp1.tar', 'HEAD']
30 - extracting common-utilities to /home/gitlab-runner/builds/pbYfs623/0/idop-automation-team/ansible/test_windows_service_down/playbooks/roles/common-utilities
31 - common-utilities was installed successfully```
````

Comment: Hi..WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi.. we have followed the same approach. we have 7 roles out of which 2 roles are not getting cloned   requirements.yml                                                                       - src: "git+ssh://git@emea-aws-gitlab.sanofi.com:2222/idop-automation-team/ansible/common-utilities.git"
scm: git

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: out of 7 roles only 5 roles are getting cloned, we are not getting any errors

Comment: re-run the same command with `-vvvv` option for verbose output this will give us more info! Also if the role is not available in general i.e if it is not public you should replace it with xxx or something as a security measure

Comment: tried above, but same result....pasted -vvvv output above

Comment: update the question with requirements.txt